# Assign date to DateField

Tags: apache-flex, datefield

I want to assign date to Date field that is in `DD-MM-YYYY` format. That is I receive String `Closure_Date`  which contains date in `DD-MM-YYYY`  format. I want to assign that date to Date field like
`dtCloseDate.selectedDate=new Date(Closure_Date);`
In this case If `Closure_Date` contains `16/11/2011`  it takes 16 as month so it takes 12 and adds remaining 4 months and  it returns `04/11/2012`.
My question is how to assign date(DD-MM-YYYY)  to DateField? 
If I use Dateformatter(DD-MM-YYYY) like `dtCloseDate.selectedDate=new Date(Dateformatter.format(Closure_Date));` It Returns `NaN`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DateField has a handy static stringToDate function that you can use to parse a date with a given format.

```
dtCloseDate.selectedDate = DateField.stringToDate("16-11-2011", "DD-MM-YYYY");
```